Good ways to help students overcome the mistake that $ 2a - 3b + 7a + 4b = -5a + 7b$
I often encounter students who incorrectly think that $ 2a - 3b + 7a + 4b = -5a + 7b,$ rather than $9a + b,$ due to the misapprehension that
$$ 2a - 3b + 7a + 4b = \color{red}{2a -}\ \color{lightblue}{3b+}\ \color{red}{7a}\ \color{lightblue}{+4b} = \color{red}{2a - 7a}\ + \color{lightblue}{3b+4b}, $$
if that makes any sense.
I feel like my methods of explanation are not the best.
Explanation $1:$
$ 2a - 3b + 7a + 4b = 2a + (-3b) + 7a + 4b.$
But this line of reasoning doesn't always catch on.
Explanation $2:$ The minus sign belongs to the $3b,$ not to the $2a.$ And so each sign belongs to the expression to the right of it.
However, I imagine this explanation is easily forgettable also.
I'm sure other math educators have come across this question from students. So what explanations of yours helped students overcome this potential ambiguity/confusion?

Perhaps having "identify the coefficient" exercises (with negative coefficients and feedback on wrong answers) immediately before these sorts of exercises would help? Does anyone have experience trying this?

Are you aware that, whatever you teach your students, you really need to drill it (or they might forget about it)?

@Dominique Sure, but there are not many great drill books for this particular exercise. I guess I can make some of my own and print them off to give to the student (which is probably what I will do), although this is time-consuming.

@AdamRubinson: Time-consuming? So what?

So I don't want to spend my time doing things if I don't have to do them? What do you mean, "TIme-consuming? So what?"

I haven't had the chance to use this in a class, but I've used this online a few times:
Tell them that subtraction doesn't 'really' exist. It's just another name for "adding the opposite": whenever they see
$$\text{[stuff]}-\text{[other stuff]}$$
it really just means:
$$\text{[stuff]}+ {}^{-}\text{[other stuff]}$$
(where the raised minus sign is the unary negation operator).
I'd give a few examples to reinforce this, too: "seven minus three" is just shorthand for "seven plus anti-three" (or "plus a loss of three"), etc.
If you encourage the habit of replacing $-$ with $+^{-}$ before doing anything else, this error should go away. (You might see some final answers that still have $+^{-}$ in them, but that's perfectly fine; if you do want to change that, it can be addressed afterwards.)

Is this different from the Explanation 1 given in the question?

@Pedro It's the same general idea, but: [1] It more clearly distinguishes subtraction from unary negation, and gives a reason for the manipulation to be meaningful. [2] I suggest introducing it in a purely arithmetic context before algebra; doing it with variables is trying to do too much at once. [3] The phrase "subtraction doesn't really exist" is a good, pithy 'hook' - especially if you talk about it like you're letting students in on some big conspiracy.

I haven't encountered this error--at least not that I'm aware of, but of course it may have escaped my notice. The way you've written it with the colors, it seems that the mistaken belief is that the minus attaches to the term before it, which I find really weird, since when we learn about minus it's either an operation between two terms or an operation (negation) performed on the thing that comes after the minus. Are you confident of your diagnosis?
I'm curious what students say when asked to explain their thinking. If asked to evaluate a similarly structured expression not containing variables, would they do it correctly? For example,
$$
2-3+7+4=?
$$
Assuming they do do that correctly, this suggests to me that students are not seeing $2a-3b+7a+4b$ and $2-3+7+4$ as the same sort of thing. Perhaps they see the former as some kind of bookkeeping exercise requiring combining like terms, whereas they see the latter as actual arithmetic.
If that's the case, perhaps it would help to point out that $2a-3b+7a+4b$ can be turned into arithmetic by assigning values to the variables. Suppose $a$ and $b$ represent two different quantities of sugar, with, say, $a$ a larger quantity and $b$ a smaller quantity. Can they see the algebraic expression as representing a process of adding and removing sugar from a bowl? If it is specified that $a$ is $1$ cup of sugar and $b$ is $1$ tablespoon of sugar (equal to $\tfrac{1}{16}$ cup), can they say how much sugar is in the bowl at the end of the process? Then ask, what is the net number of additions to the bowl using the cup measure and the net number of additions to the bowl using the tablespoon measure?

Adam:

I don't believe there is a "magic explanation" that will fix these problems.  Whether in some fancy words, or colloquial ones, or even an analogy. It's fine, even useful, to say what the student did wrong.  And when you do, use simple/colloquial words, not set theory terms.  But citing the concept should always be in the context of correction.  (I.e. you did it wrong, let's do it again.)  Operant training (like of an animal) is more the model than having an instruction set for a computer.  Again, of course we have more reason than animals...but still think "training", not "instruction".  The explanations given are en passant with the exercises.

You, the kid, etc. should be doing lots of intermediate algebra.  Step by step.  Lots of lines!  Once they have facility, they can group faster.  But for kids that are struggling with pre-algebra--and it is sort of new and "fancy" to have "letters, not numbers--it is good to have them do/show every small change.  For one it reduces mistakes.  For another, it just gives more experience in manipulation.  For another it makes things a little less mysterious (how terms are combined).

For this specific type of problem, I like the use of parentheses on the intermediate algebra lines as you group terms and before doing the operation to combine them.

This problem is actually medium complexity (two variables, four terms, some negative signs).  Would encourage you to make sure the student can do easier problems first (with lots of drill).  And try to build up the difficulty scale.  For example what about simplifying 4a + 2b +3a?  And yes, he (or you) should show the intermediate steps, write explicit lines, USE PARENTHESES, even on simple problems like the above.  It's good practice as you all move to the trickier ones.


P.s.  Good luck.  I'm sorry your kid is struggling and/or you got stuck with a weak one.  But he can still master this stuff.  And you can help him.

For clarity, here's how I might do/show this and train the kid to do it (in front of me):
2a−3b+7a+4b= ?
["Keep track of the negative signs! And move the terms around so like is with like."]
2a+7a-3b+4b
["Use parentheses to emphasize what goes with what."]
(2a+7a) + (-3b+4b)
["Combine terms.  Do the addition or subtraction.  Watch out for that -3b thingie!"]
(9a) + (4b-3b)
["Keep going."]
(9a) + (1b)
["OK, now take the parentheses off."]
9a + 1b
So, possibly as many as 5 lines of work.  Certainly at least 3.  NOT only 2. Not for a weak kid.

Note that another source of complexity are equalities with terms on each side.  One never "throws over the equals and changes sign", but instead explicitly subtracts or adds terms to each side, to cancel them out on one side.
Yes, it is the same result.  And for accomplished users it is fine to "throws over the equals and changes sign".  But no, not for kids starting out.  (They will forget to change the sign.)  Instead, they have to laboriously write out intermediate lines of algebra and show the process as an addition or subtraction made to each side.  Along with some counsel that "you treat each side of the equals sign, equally".*
*The "real analysis, function-lover" pedants will note issues like division by zero or squaring/rooting complications.  But do NOT mention this at the time.  Deal with this later, when you get to problems that require it.  It is NOT an issue for subtraction and addition.  And you don't want to give initial instruction that is too complicated/caveated.  Deal with it later as a new issue.
New P.s.  I wonder if you are working with the kids in person and both working by hand or are somewhat online/typing.  I (as well as others on this site) were curious how the particular negative sign error were coming in.  But I noticed as I typed my response that with typing, especially with some ctrl-c/ctrl-v-ing that I started to introduce that error.  But it does not come in if working by hand (even if online, better to use a slate or camera or the like, sort of like in many YT videos or Khan Academy].

It is not one kid that I have come across that has this problem: it is many!

I completely believe it.  It is a common difficulty.  When I said "him" that was for example.  It might be many different hims.  Or hers.  Math is hard, as Barbie wisely told us.  ;)

I like to draw vertical lines (pre-absolute value learning) or boxes separating each term from each other, emphasizing that the sign of the number is in front of it (reading from left to right). That way, students can rearrange the terms with the proper signs before combining like terms. Reading the problem out loud can also help students realize that the sign is in front of the number!
"Two a minus 3 b plus 7 a plus 4 b" - the minus is attached to the 3b
$2a-3b+7a+4b$
$[2a][-3b][+7a][+4b]$
$[2a+7a]+[-3b+4b]$
$9a+b$

I haven't see that problem myself, so this is just an untried idea:
From early on, students are taught to add numbers in columns. You can tell them explicitly that the same can be done when adding terms in an equation.  That is:
2a−3b+7a+4b
...is the same as...
2a     -3b
7a      4b
-----------
9a      1b

This is essentially breaking the problem down into smaller steps: (1) segregating like terms; (2) assigning the appropriate sign to each term; and only then (3) adding the terms.
Notice that you do something similar when solving simultaneous equations and align like terms from different equations in columns so that one equation can be subtracted from another.
As an added benefit, this is a way of "showing your work" and gives you some insight into where (which one of these 3 sub-steps) the student is making the mistake.

To me it seems like someone told these students about the commutativity of addition as, "$a + b = b + a$, so anytime you see $a + b$ you can replace it with $b + a$". And the student misperceives:
$$2a − 3b + 7a + 4b = 2a − (3b + 7a) + 4b = 2a − (7a + 3b) + 4b = 2a −  7a + 3b + 4b $$
My take would be to emphasize that signs have the same order as multiplying, that is, they bind more tightly than addition. So if you commute terms around, you have to take the signs of those terms with them. For me, usually getting a student to agree that $-5 = (-1)5$ gets them on the path to see that signs are in the same order of operations as multiplying.
Here's a longer blog article I wrote in the past around issues like these: Automatic Negatives.

Your explanation doesn't explain why the students get $7b$ rather than $b$ in the final expression. It's also not clear why students would perceive the minus sign as belonging to the next two terms rather than to the next three (or however many) terms. My guess, and it's only a guess, is that students see "$2a-$" and realize something is to be subtracted from $2a$. But then they think that $3b$ "can't be subtracted", so they go on to subtract the next thing that "can" be subtracted, namely $7a$.

How about take out the common factor?
$$\begin{aligned}2a - 3b + 7a + 4b
&=(???)a+(???)b\\
&=(2+7)a+(-3+4)b\\
&=9a+b\\
\end{aligned}$$
Then you explain that to find out $???$ they must take the numbers that multiply $a$ and $b$, respectively. Actually, this is the correct way to combine like terms.
Edit
You can explain this by highlighting the terms with $a$ and saying that the numbers highlighted with $a$ are the ones that go inside the parentheses of $a$. Similarly, for $b$:
$$\underline{2a} \;\underline{\underline{-\; 3b}} +\underline{7a} + \underline{\underline{4b}}
=(\underline{\qquad})a+(\underline{\underline{\qquad}})b$$
In this sense, the procedure becomes visual.

How will this resolve the issue? Surely the mistaken student will think that the first $???$ is replaced by $2-7.$

@AdamRubinson You could try to explain that the numbers that multiply $a$, which will be $???$, are the numbers that are "attached to" $a$. Can the student understand what "attached" means?

@AdamRubinson See my edit.

All these things contain zero minus-signs, hence they are all equal:
$p+q+r+s$
$p+q+s+r$
$p+r+q+s$
$p+r+s+q$
$p+s+r+q$
$p+s+q+r$
$q+p+r+s$
$q+p+s+r$
$q+r+p+s$
$q+r+s+p$
$q+s+p+r$
$q+s+r+p$
$r+p+q+s$
$r+p+s+q$
$r+q+p+s$
$r+q+s+p$
$r+s+p+q$
$r+s+q+p$
$s+p+q+r$
$s+p+r+q$
$s+q+p+r$
$s+q+r+q$
$s+r+p+q$
$s+r+q+p$
=> You make a big poster out of this, clearly showing the power of commutativity and associativity of the plus-operator.
What about minus?
There are three minus-signs:

Sign of a negative number: $-_S2, -_S1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...$
Unary Operator, multiplying a number by $-_S1$: $-_U(5) = (-_S1) \times 5 = -_S5$
$-_U(-_S3) = (-_S1) \times (-_S3) = 3, ...$
Binary operator: $a -_B b = a + (-_U(b))$
Example: $2a - 3b = 2a + (-3b)$
Exercise:
$2a -_B 3b + 4a + 7b = 2a + (-_U(3b)) + 4a + 7b = 2a + (-_S3b) + 4a + 7b = 2a + 4a + (-_S3)b + 7b= (2+4) \times a $

Once they get the hang of it, you can simplify to:
$2a - 3b + 4a + 7b = (2a) + (-3b) + (4a) + (7b)$
$                  = (2a) + (4a) + (-3b) + (7b)$
$      = (2+4) \times a + (-3 + 7) \times b$
$      = 6a + 4b$

This seems inappropriate for the level of secondary school (kids aged 11-16). Have you actually explained this to a student of that age such that they understood all this?

I learnt it in Belgium when I was $12$ :-) I must admit: we just learnt that the minus-sign has three meanings, without using the "underfixes" ($_U$, $_B$ or $_S$).

I think this is probably the best answer so far. I think teaching it in the non-axiomatic way is probably best for children (so in a way like you said: the minus sign has three meanings without axiomatic notation). I'm not sure kids that age (11-16) learn via axioms, except for maybe the more advanced students.

Why the downvotes?

(I didn't downvote)
